# Delete if just one record in the join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables users and offices

user.rb

```
has_many :offices
```

office.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Then I have officesuser table where I have office_id and user_id fields.

I am trying to create a destroy action for office something like this.

officer_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  render json: {}, status: :unprocessable_entity unless office.destroy
end

private

def office
  @office ||= Office.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the destroy action I want to delete the user as well if there is only one office associated with the user. So basically delete the user as well if there is no other office then belongs the the user otherwise don't delete the user.

Comment: It sounds like office and user should have a has_and_belongs_to_many association to each other, especially since you mentioned a join model. If it is a many to one like you described then you don't need a join model.

Comment: @Joel_Blum an office can belong to only one user. but a user can have many offices

Comment: Yes that's called many to one, you do not need a join table (officeuser) for this. Since office can belong to only one user it's enough to have a user_id on office.

Answer (score 0):

After the office destroy successful you can check whether the user link to any other office or not to determine destroy that user as well or not:

```rb
# office.rb
after_destroy :destroy_no_office_user_as_well

private

def destroy_no_office_user_as_well
 user.destroy if user.offices.empty?
end
```

If you concern about what if that user has new office in the same time, then can move destroy logic into user class and check with lock.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.